# Can I backup my APN settings?

Tags: backup, apn

Where are my Access Point Names stored in the file system? Can I back them up via `adb shell`?

My phone is unlocked (AT&T Contract. *Le sigh*.) and I'm inching towards modding it but I want to be sure I've got my APN settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just copy the `/system/etc/apns-conf.xml` file.

You can also use an app like APN Backup & Restore: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.riteshsahu.APNBackupRestore

**Edit:** To backup manually-entered APNs (or ones otherwise not part of your ROM, such as ones "imported" when you insert a new SIM card) you also need to back up

```
/data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/com.android.settings_preferences.x­ml
```

APN Backup & Restore does not do this.

Comment: I actually just dug out /system/etc/apns-conf.xml but ... that file contains the default T-Mobile APNs not the APN that I entered manually for AT&T. Under Settings > Mobile Network > Access Point Names on my phone itself I see the correct APN for my carrier. Where is *that* stored?

Comment: (An academic question. I'm just curious. I copied the settings I need using the age old "eyeball and pen" method.)

Comment: Hmm, that's a good question.  I just checked mine and it doesn't have info for my carrier either ... can't find any information about it or files that look promising.  Maybe it's in a database somewhere.

Comment: Ha!  Found it!  `/data/data/com.android.settings/shared_prefs/com.android.settings_preferences.xml`.  Note it only seems to contain the current APN, so if you entered more than one the others aren't there.  I don't know where the others are.

Comment: I've just got one. That's it. Perfect.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you can restore by just replacing the com.android.settings_preferences.xml file.  I think the actual data is in a db somewhere.

Comment: The db for the actual data is in "/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony.databses/telephony.db" --> http://bradchow.wordpress.com/2009/02/26/apns-file-in-android/