# How to restore APN Settings?

Tags: settings, apn

I edited my Android phone's APN Settings. I did **not** have a back up of my APN Settings file [`/system/etc/apns-conf.xml`]as mentioned in this [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7154/can-i-backup-my-apn-settings).

I deleted the **Proxy** and **Port** fields from my APN Settings. Currently, my device is showing "Not Set" for those two fields as I deleted those 2.

Is there a way I can get my earlier APN settings back? Will remove and adding the SIM Card solve the issue?

Android Device: **Samsung Tab 2** running 4.1 and Mobile carrier: Idea Network (Country:India)

Comment: I'm totally unfamiliar with your carrier, but I found [this link](https://www.komparify.com/blogs/index.php/apn/idea.html) that has some APN settings. Not sure if they're totally accurate, but otherwise I would call customer service.

Comment: As stated below you can send SMS **SET** to 54671 for internet settings and you can install them (this is IDEA n/w specific). Also configure APN manually - Title>Idea, APN>internet, and everything else as blank or default values. You need not to configure proxy.